# Switch contents of footer based on page

Tags: sharepoint, visual-studio-2013, reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2011, bids

Switch contents of footer

Is it possible to switch the contents of the footer based on the page number?

On the first page, I would like to show a text based footer, and on the last page I would like to show a logo.

I've tried adding:

```
=IIf(Globals!PageNumber<>1,logo1,logo2)
```

In the Report Data section within the Images folder, the logos are embedded as logo1 and logo2.

Image Properties > General > Use this image, in the (fx) button, but once I have compiled the project, i am unable to upload the rdl file to Dynamics.

Also, as soon as I add the above script to the image, the image becomes a broken image in the design view, and as soon as I replace the above script with the original script which was simply

`logo1`

everything is back to normal again, the image can be see in the designer, and the file can be uploaded into dynamics.

If this is possible, would appreciate some help.

Comment: I am not sure if this is causing your problem uploading to Dynamics but try surrounding the image names with double quotes, `"logo1"` and `"logo2"`.

Comment: @alejandrozuleta, unfortunately, that didn't work.

Comment: Does the report run in visual studio using theconditional logo expression?

Comment: @alejandrozuleta, it's doesn't.  With that expression, the image container ends up showing a broken image symbol.

Comment: Which error do you get when uploading to CRM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to surround the image names with quotes, as mentioned in the comments. Additionally, the image will appear broken in the designer. If you preview or upload to CRM, the image will show correctly.

Double-check that both images are embedded in the report:

[image: Embedded images]

Ensure that the image source is set to Embedded:

[image: Select the image source: Embedded]

Ensure that the image names are surrounded by quotes:

[image: Image name surrounded by quotes]

After this, the report can either be previewed or uploaded to CRM. The image on the first page will be different from the image on the remaining pages, as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should add both images to the footer. Then change the visibility property of each to suit your needs:
Last page only
=IIF(Globals!PageNumber=Globals!TotalPages,False,True)

First page only
=IIF(Globals!PageNumber=1,False,True)